# MySQL Query always returns only '1' in azure app service + azure database server

Tags: php, mysql, azure, azure-appservice, azure-mysql-database

Currently, I am coding using azure app service and azure database server for mysql.

When the 'select' statement is executed, only '1' is returned.

I don't think it's a connection problem because 'insert' statement works fine.

This is my php code running on azure app service.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
include('dbconnectr.php'); 

$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $con->prepare('select * from contents where id='.$id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
echo $result;
```

What is the problem?

Comment: warning - your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: If this is mysqli, `fetch()` returns a boolean, and you need to use `$stmt->bind_result()` to specify variables that receive the selected columns.

Comment: What are you expecting to echo instead? In PDO, `fetch()` returns an array, you can't echo that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will help you

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
include('dbconnectr.php'); 

$id = $_GET['id'];

$stmt = $con->prepare("select * from contents where id=?");

/* bind parameters */
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($result);

/* fetch value */
$stmt->fetch();

print_r($result);
```

I use the bind for protecting myself from sql injection. 
So I use `bind_param` to bind the param, then use `execute` for execute the command and then bind the result in the `bind_result` and after that use the fetch and fill the result variable and Done